# Azure storage analytics log parse error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm getting parse exceptions when using [WindowsAzure.Storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) to access storage analytics logs.

This is my code for retrieving log records:

```
var recordList = this.SourceAnalyticsClient.ListLogRecords(
    this.Service, this.StartTime, null, this.Configuration.BlobRequestOptions,
    this.CreateOperationContext())
    .ToList();
```

That code throws the following exception:

> **Error parsing log record: could not parse 'Wednesday, 03-Dec-14 08:59:27 GMT' using format: dddd, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'** (type InvalidOperationException)
>   Exception stack trace:
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Analytics.LogRecordStreamReader.ReadDateTimeOffset(String format)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Analytics.LogRecord.PopulateVersion1Log(LogRecordStreamReader reader)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Analytics.LogRecord..ctor(LogRecordStreamReader reader)

I'm guessing this happens because my thread is not using an English culture.

I need a way to resolve this problem or a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investing this a little bit I found that `LogRecordStreamReader.ReadDateTimeOffset` is specifying a `null` format provider parameter to `DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact`. That means that the thread's current culture will be used - and that won't work for threads using non-English cultures.

A possible workaround is:

```
// Remember current culture setting
CultureInfo originalThreadCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

try
{
    // Assign the invariant culture temporarily
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    // Let WindowsAzure.Storage parse log records
    recordList = this.SourceAnalyticsClient.ListLogRecords(
        this.Service, this.StartTime, null, this.Configuration.BlobRequestOptions,
        this.CreateOperationContext())
        .ToList();
}
finally
{
    // Restore original culture setting
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalThreadCulture;
}
```

I've also created a [pull request with a suggested fix](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/pull/95).